# What are the technical reasons why Linux does not support the distribution of binary drivers to be installed on existing Linux setups?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Any Linux Kernel module can put symbols in the Public Symbol table by using the EXPORT_SYMBOL directive.  So why is it considered non-conventional to install binary drivers (that you didn't compile locally yourself using your local header files)?  The kernel would export all the symbols that a reasonable driver would need to access.  The driver would export all its entry points.  So it's binary should be install-able, right?

I've seen some websites giving instructions to download a binary driver and install it, but most experts say that's not really supported in Linux.  You should really only use drivers that were upstream in your kernel when you got it.  Or at least you should download the source code and compile it locally then install it.  Why?

Comment: There are ways to install binaries, e.g., using DKMS -- which builds a binary interface to the kernel for a particular driver.  Modern Linux kernels us modversions, which obstruct drivers from loading if they were not built for a particular kernel, although there are ways around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the kernel API is not stable. This means, that there may be subtle API differences (such as layout changes of internal structures) even between consecutive minor revisions of the kernel tree. To make the problem worse, there's no easy way to track those changes - one could easily add versioning information to functions (there are not too many of those), but trying to do so with every internal data structure in the kernel will be an exercise in futility - any module can, in theory, access any data structure in the kernel, there are no internal API isolation barriers (such as user/kernel space boundary, which is very stable API wise).

To illustrate a problem, imagine that you've got an existing kernel API looking like this:

```
struct s {
     int foo;
     int bar;
};

void exported_symbol(struct s *s_ptr);
```

And then somebody goes on and changes the code a little, to the tune of:

```
struct s {
    const char *funny_name;
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

void exported_symbol(struct s *s_ptr);
```

Will the binary driver still load (can be forced to)? Yes, it will. Will the driver function as expected - very probably not, possibly taking the whole system down with it.

Even if the binary module matches your kernel version exactly, there's still another hurdle to consider, namely differences in kernel build configuration (as defined by `.config` file in the kernel source tree and can be examined on most installations via `/proc/config(.gz)`). The data structures, as seen by the compiler, may change rather considerably depending on the variables set (check out `linux/timer.h` for an example of widely and frequently used API which is sensitive to kernel build configuration).

Comment: You should also add that structure members also depend on the config used to compile it through `#ifdef`s so even the same kernel version can have multiple different structure member combinations.

Comment: True. Added relevant passage.

Comment: OK what if it was like this:
The kernel header file had:
int foobar;
void export_symbol(int foobar);

But my driver was compile with a header that had:
char foobar;

Comment: OK what if it was like this:

/* The kernel header had this */
int foobar;
void export_symbol(int foobar);

/* But my driver was compiled with a header that had */
char foobar;

In that case would the insmod linker catch the incompatibility?

Comment: I doubt it would but I haven't personally tried it.